# jqGrid throws error when trying to use editrules for inline editing

Tags: javascript, jqgrid

I have a basic jqGrid set up with inline editing and it working really well. However, when I try to use `editrules` and validation fails, it throws this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'msg' of undefined
```

After looking into it a bit, it seems that it can't find the text to display the validation error.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/dpatz/6KykC/) is my jsFiddle with the error. You can get it to be thrown by inline editing (clicking on) a cell in the "Client" colum, deleting all the text and hitting enter or clicking on a different cell.

Any advice here would be helpful. I'd prefer to not write my own validation for jqGrid but is it a possibility if a solution can't be found...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is very simple. You have to include `i18n/grid.locale-en.js` file additionally (see [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3afirst_grid)). The modified jsFiddle demo is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/6KykC/1/).